# 2-speed 2-direction gearbox design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanical

I need to design a gearbox with the following properties:

- The direction of rotation is maintained between the input and output shaft
- The input shaft can be rotated in one direction for one gear ratio (e.g. 1:1000)
- The input shaft can be rotated in the other direction for a different gear ratio (e.g. 1:10)

I have done a significant amount of research and have not been able to come up with any simple designs. I've considered ratcheting mechanisms and could probably make a working design using them but they require many parts and I want the simplest/cheapest possible solution. I feel like there must be some mechanism I've overlooked.

The gearbox is to be driven by a smallish DC motor (~100 watts).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A hydrauiic pump and two motors with bypass valves.

Comment: For you, perhaps just connect the same shaft to a fixed ratio gearbox through a one-way bearing. Then do it again to the same shaft with a second gearbox with a different ratio and one-way bearing in the other direction. Then gang the output shafts together.

Comment: Maybe this can be done with a planetary gearbox, where one of the ring gear brakes that normally changes gears is replaced by a one way bearing.